# defaultPageTransition on ASP.net MVC4 with jQuery Mobile

Tags: jquery-mobile, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm using ASP.net MVC4 with jquery mobile.

i'm trying to change the transition page effect setting `$.mobile.defaultPageTransition` to `'none'` in `'mobileinit'` bind, but nothing happens and the default transition (slide) persists!

I even tried alter jquery.mobile-1.0.js directly and nothing changes too.

anyone have any tips?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you binding to `mobileinit` in the correct place?

```
<script src="jquery.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).bind("mobileinit", function(){
    $.mobile.defaultPageTransition = 'none';
});
</script>
<script src="jquery-mobile.js"></script>
```

Notice jQuery Core gets loaded first, then we bind to the `mobileinit` event, then the jQuery Mobile JS file is loaded.

Docs: http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.1.0-rc.1/docs/api/globalconfig.html

Here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/JczRj/

Comment: You is right! i'd this in mind... i think the problem is in the code bellow. i guess it's loading the bundle with wrong dependencies.

`<script src="@System.Web.Optimization.BundleTable.Bundles.
    ResolveBundleUrl("~/Scripts/js")"></script>` but still not working :(